# How to get final cost product with season table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get final cost product with season table?

I have this SQL schema.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79bb30/4/0

**and I use this SQL**

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE(t1.cost, t1.base_price, `ec_products`.`price`) AS final_cost
FROM `ec_products`
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT ec_season.cost,
          ec_season.base_price,
          ec_season.product_id
   FROM ec_season
   WHERE Duration =
       (SELECT MAX(Duration)
        FROM ec_season
        WHERE `Duration` <= 4 ) ) AS t1 ON `t1`.`product_id` = `ec_products`.`id`
```

However, this SQL query has the bug for product id 1. It gives wrong price 30.3.
But must give this price 40.00.
Because MAX(Duration) <= 4 must be 2 and price 40.
Can you help me with this?

**I also tried this**

```
SELECT ec_season.cost,
              ec_season.base_price,
              ec_season.product_id
       FROM ec_season
       WHERE Duration =
           (SELECT ec_season.product_id ,  MAX(ec_season.Duration) 
FROM ec_season WHERE `Duration` <= 4 GROUP BY ec_season.product_id)
```

But it give me this error

## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 columns

Example of seasons table

[image]

Comment: You compare Duration with 2 columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
   WHERE Duration = (SELECT ec_season.product_id , 
                            MAX(ec_season.Duration) 
                     FROM ec_season
                     WHERE `Duration` <= 4
                     GROUP BY ec_season.product_id
                    )
```

The `=` should be followed by a *scalar* subquery.  A scalar subquery returns one column (and no more than one row).

Presumably, you intend:

```
 FROM ec_season s
 WHERE s.Duration = (SELECT MAX(s2.Duration) 
                     FROM ec_season s2
                     WHERE s2.Duration <= 4 AND
                           s2.product_id = s.product_id
                    )
```

Comment: Now I have this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b28b0/3
http://prntscr.com/l24rvo  product with id 1 is duplicated but must be $ 40. Which corresponds to the range of dates.
This http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b28b0/4 don't give a seasonal price at all.
Can you tell how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to match multiple columns `product_id` and `Duration` from the Subquery. This is a [Row Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/row-subqueries.html); and MySQL allows tuple matching.

Try:

```
SELECT ec_season.cost,
              ec_season.base_price,
              ec_season.product_id
       FROM ec_season
       WHERE (ec_season.product_id, Duration) =
             (
              SELECT ec_season.product_id, MAX(ec_season.Duration) 
              FROM ec_season 
              WHERE `Duration` <= 4 
              GROUP BY ec_season.product_id
             )
```